# Python3 puts a 'b' in front of date

Tags: python

This Python 3 code:

```
commentmsg =   '\n' +  svn_date + ' Repo: '+ svn_repository  + ' Rev: ' + svn_revision  + ' User: ' + svn_author + '\n'
```

gives this result:

```
b'2020-01-29' b'09:26:49' Repo: SubversionTraining Rev: 478 User: bengt.nilsson
```

There is a 'b' in front of date and time, where does it come from and how do I get rid of it? 
This started with Python 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: Can you give the output of `type(svn_date)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because one of your variables is probably of type `bytes` instead of `str` (the `b` represents a `bytes` object). Try doing the following:

```
raw_data = [svn_date, svn_repository, svn_revision, svn_author]
data = [ele.decode() for ele in raw_data if isinstance(ele, bytes) else ele]
commentmsg = f"\n{data[0]} Repo: {data[1]} Rev: {data[2]} User: {data[3]}"
```

Comment: Actually, `str()` (as well as f-strings) won't work with `bytes` (i.e. it'll call `repr()` under the scenes and still return `b"xxxx"`). You need to `decode()` the bytes to string using an encoding like `utf-8`.

Comment: @trolley813 thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: @trolley813 See my edit; will it work now?

Comment: Actually, the code looks like this:
            svn_longdate        = svnlookup('date', svn_repo_path, svn_revision).split()
            svn_date            = '%s %s' % (svn_longdate[0], svn_longdate[1])
            svn_repository      = os.path.basename(svn_repo_path)
            svn_message_line    = svn_message.replace('"','\'\'').split('\r\n')
            commentmsg =   '\n' +  svn_date + ' Repo: '+ svn_repository  + ' Rev: ' + svn_revision  + ' User: ' + svn_author + '\n'
I tried to put .decode(utf-8) on variables but then I get the message "'list' object has no attribute 'decde'"